# Why are my objects in event args missing properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling, devexpress

I have in WPF, using devexpress, a situation where I have a DragDropManager with the event handler in code-behind. When I drag a row onto the grid control, the event handler is called as expected. My problem is that the control wrapped inside the event args has most of its defining properties replaced by question marks '?', so I can't really get any identifying information from the source control (from which I dragged the row).
[Image of the situation described above](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/4310a6c9-2400-11e6-80bf-00155d62480c).

Now, a snippet of my view follows below. The snippet contains first the control to which the row is dragged onto, afterwards the control from which the row is dragged. For simplicity I have removed the columns.

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataViewSheets}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataViewSheet}"  MaxHeight="300" Height="300" DefaultSorting="Name" x:Name="grc_sheets">
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TableView Name="firstView" AllowBestFit="True" ShowColumnHeaders="True"
                                        ShowVerticalLines="false" ShowHorizontalLines="True" ShowIndicator="False" IsDetailButtonVisibleBinding="{Binding Row.HasChildren, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                </dxg:TableView>
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <dxg:GridDragDropManager AllowDrag="False" AllowDrop="True" AllowScrolling="True" Drop="GridDragDropManager_OnDrop"/>
                            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
                                <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourcePath="DataViewAttributes">
                                    <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                                        <dxg:GridControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataViewAttributeViewModel}" x:Name="grc_sheetAttributes">
                                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False" DetailHeaderContent="DataControlDetailDescriptor" AutoWidth="False" ShowVerticalLines="false" ShowHorizontalLines="True" ShowIndicator="False" IsDetailButtonVisibleBinding="{Binding Row.HasChildren, Mode=TwoWay}"></dxg:TableView>
                                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                            <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
                                                <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourcePath="ChildDataViewAttributes">
                                                    <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                                                        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grc_childAttributes">
                                                            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors> </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>                                              <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                                <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False" DetailHeaderContent="DataControlDetailDescriptor" AutoWidth="False" ShowVerticalLines="false" ShowHorizontalLines="False" ShowIndicator="False" IsDetailButtonVisibleBinding="{Binding Row.HasChildren, Mode=TwoWay}"></dxg:TableView>
                                                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                                        </dxg:GridControl>
                                                    </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                                                </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
                                            </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
                                        </dxg:GridControl>
                                    </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor.DataControl>
                                </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
                            </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
                        </dxg:GridControl>

<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentDomain.EntityClasses}" x:Name="grc_availableAttributes">
                                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                    <dxg:TreeListView DataRowTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" TreeDerivationMode="HierarchicalDataTemplate" ShowVerticalLines="False" ShowHorizontalLines="False" ShowIndicator="False"/>
                                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <dxg:TreeListDragDropManager AllowDrag="True" AllowDrop="False"/>
                                </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </dxg:GridControl>
```

Around these gridcontrol I have a LayoutControl with a number of LayoutGroups inside it, just to keep everything in place.

I have tried extracting this into a boiled-down sample project and asked DevExpress support to help with, but the solutions I have gotten so far, have not helped. The extracted sample actually worked, I could see the gridcontrol and all of its properties. When I then tried putting the exact same thing back into my original project, it didn't work any longer. The only difference was really with my viewmodels, not implementing a few of the things I in the original project.

Could it really be that my viewmodels are having an impact on the event args, despite the event being handled directly in the code-behind?

Follow-up question: Have any of you experienced the same sort of thing, where properties "disappear"? If yes, what was your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Just for the fun of it, I today tried just getting the various properties of e.SourceControl, to see if they could actually be resolved (in lack of a better word) or they would just end up throwing an exception or being null.
Here is what I did:

```
private void GridDragDropManager_OnDrop(object sender, GridDropEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = e.SourceControl;
        var name = control.Name;
        var draggedRowContent = (EntityAttribute)e.DraggedRows[0];
        ((DataViewViewModel)DataContext).Execute_DropEntityAttribute(e);
    }
```

As expected the e.SourceControl still showed '?' for most of the properties, but when trying to fetch the different properties I actually get the expected result. Even adding the control to the watch list, would expose more of the proeprties than just looking at it through the debugger.
Conclusion; it seems that the Visual Studio Debugger
has some kinks in the machinery, which should be worked out.